# Mystery, variable path name

Tags: php, cakephp

This works:

```
    function upload($directory) {
      App::import('Vendor', 'UploadedFiles', array('file' => 'UploadedFiles.php'));

      echo $directory;
      $this->_saveUploadedFiles('C:/xampp/htdocs/freetickets/app/webroot/img/gallery/zantje_11042/');
    }

  function _saveUploadedFiles($galleryPath) {

    $absGalleryPath = $galleryPath;
    $absThumbnailsPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\freetickets\app\webroot\img\gallery\zantje_11042\thumbnails\\';

    //Iterate through uploaded data and save the original file, thumbnail, and description.
    while(($file = UploadedFiles::fetchNext()) !== null) {
      $fileName = $file->getSourceFile()->getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath);
      $file->getSourceFile()->save($absGalleryPath . '/' . $fileName);

      $thumbFileName = $file->getThumbnail(1)->getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath);
      $file->getThumbnail(1)->save($absThumbnailsPath . '/' . $thumbFileName);
    }
  }
```

But this doesn't:

```
        function upload($directory) {
      App::import('Vendor', 'UploadedFiles', array('file' => 'UploadedFiles.php'));

      echo $directory; //echoes C:/xampp/htdocs/freetickets/app/webroot/img/gallery/zantje_11042/
      $this->_saveUploadedFiles($directory);
    }

  function _saveUploadedFiles($galleryPath) {

    $absGalleryPath = $galleryPath;
    $absThumbnailsPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\freetickets\app\webroot\img\gallery\zantje_11042\thumbnails\\';

    //Iterate through uploaded data and save the original file, thumbnail, and description.
    while(($file = UploadedFiles::fetchNext()) !== null) {
      $fileName = $file->getSourceFile()->getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath);
      $file->getSourceFile()->save($absGalleryPath . '/' . $fileName);

      $thumbFileName = $file->getThumbnail(1)->getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath);
      $file->getThumbnail(1)->save($absThumbnailsPath . '/' . $thumbFileName);
    }
  }
```

**Only difference** is the     `$this->_saveUploadedFiles('C:/xampp/htdocs/freetickets/app/webroot/img/gallery/zantje_11042/')`     and one with a variable as path:    `$this->_saveUploadedFiles($directory);`

So why doesn't it work when using $directory, even if `$directory` echoes C:/xampp/htdocs/freetickets/app/webroot/img/gallery/zantje_11042/ ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the non-working one do?

Comment: Probably something to do w/ images. Anyways, I don't think it's really a good idea to use absolute URLs. Check paths.php somewhere in cake/, it provides pretty much all of the constants you might need.

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you have put / and \ as folder separators in paths.

Comment: Or he can use the DS constant.